# Can analytical precision be finer than a lower detection limit?

Tags: aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry, concentration

Can analytical precision be finer than a lower detection limit?

For example, if the lower detection limit of an analytical method is reported as 0.010 ppm. Is it possible to have an analytical precision of 0.001 ppm, and therefore a measurement like 0.116 ppm?

Obviously this depends significantly on the method, but in theory is this possible?

Comment: There's no inherent contradiction, I think. Detection limit doesn't necessarily stem from lack of precision.

Comment: @JoshuaWright, The question is how did you determine the detection limit? The problem is multiple methods will yield different detection limits for the same analyte or the same analytical method. There is no true "definition" of detection limit nor there is any ideal way of determining it.

Comment: Yes this is obviously possible.  For many methods of interest, the method will be precisely tailored to a particular measurement range.  For example, a technique might have a precision of 0.001 ppm when analyzing solutions that are between 0.114 and 0.118 ppm in concentration, and have rapidly declining precision outside of this range.  Isotope ratio mass spectrometry comes to mind as a related example.

Comment: @CurtF. Thanks for your comment, I suspected this was the case. Any chance you know where I could find a isotope ratio mass spectrometry data set that shows this?

Comment: @CurtF. Wouldn't that allow you to spike a sample to increase the concentration of an analyte and then, by extrapolating from higher concentration, to determine an analyte concentration in the original sample that is below the detection limit? For instance, if I can determine the concentration of original sample + spike as $x+dx$ and that of spike solution as $x$, then by simple subtraction I know $dx$. If what you write is true $dx$ could be below the detection limit

Comment: @Buck Torn.  Good thought experiment.  I think a key consideration is how exactly you know $x$.  Is it really practicable to get infinite precision in your assumed value of $x$?

Comment: One situation that illustrates how infinite precision in $x$ is impossible is shot noise in counts-based data.  Suppose the application is DNA sequencing, and you are measuring counts of covid amplicon from a PCR and counts of a control amplicon from the same PCR.  If you get 100,004 counts for the viral genome-derived molecule, and 100,000 counts for the spike-in amplicon, you can be sure the ratio of concentrations in the original sample is 0.500 (maybe even better, I havne't done the math.  But you can't then dilute the sample before spike-in by 100,000-fold and hope to get 4 counts.

Comment: @CurtF. One does not need infinite precision to do what I suggest, just precision higher than the lower limit of detection. I'm sure there is a flaw in the argument, such as problems with extrapolation (uncertainty growing when you extrapolate). I'm also starting to suspect this question might be more appropriate at cross validated SE